# Ubuntu Source fbgrab works when I compile it does not work

Tags: ubuntu, png, framebuffer

Hi I am trying to grab images from framebuffer. 
fbgrab does this perfectly. 
The fb grab that is installed on ubuntu(the one I installed from the software center)
works perfectly.
When I compiled the source and run it. THe images are all tilted.

I was getting the same issue before I looked into the source of fb grab.

What could be the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the reason
fbgrab actually does not use the code that comes from the repose but it actually calls

fbcat and the output is piped into png converter.